# Django allauth render login fields manually user or email not displayed

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to display the login fields manually, instead of using:

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

I'm setting allauth as follows in order to login with email:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

In HTML I have the following:

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Email input -->
  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    {{form.email}}
    <label class="form-label" for="form2Example1">Email address</label>
  </div>

  <!-- Password input -->
  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    {{form.password}}
    <label class="form-label" for="form2Example2">Password</label>
  </div>
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
  </form>
```

The email field is not being displayed, I have also tried with:

```
{{form.user}}
```

and the field is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

Use: `{{ form.login }}`

You can see field types by first outputting them with `{{ form.as_p }}`
then use your browser's inspect tool to see the html code for that field
there is a `<input (some attributes) id="id_{fieldname}">`